# Firefox won't show localStorage for a domain even when the values are there

Tags: firefox, local-storage

> **TL;DR:** Firefox won't show localStorage for a domain and I need to get some data from there.

I need to copy the value of a localStorage element, which is a really long string so just echoing on the console won't work, because it's truncated.
Both Safari and Chrome do echo the whole string to the console, but not Firefox, and I need to do this on Firefox because here is where that specific value is stored.

Firefox's storage tab used to show this value, now it won't, and it won't even show any of the other keys for this domain, so even short strings are not shown there either.

I could configure my local web server for https and then send it this value with an XMLHttpRequest, but I'm hoping for a simpler solution. Any ideas?

In the image here you can see how locaStorage does have values, but the storage tab won't show them, and that was the only way I could copy the long string.
[image]

Comment: I’ve got the same problem. I have a script that saves some data from web pages into the local storage and there’s a case specifically correcting two pages updating a value at the same time, overwriting each other, which occurs extremely rarely, but now it did occur for the first time. And right after it happened, I couldn’t see any local storage entries, even though the data was still there. There appears to be a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1383030) for this.

Answer (score -1):

Firefox's console has a [`copy` helper function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers#copy) that will copy its argument to your clipboard, with no truncation:

```
copy(localStorage.getItem("wzSave_Audio"))
```